# "message sent to deallocated instance" - Can't find a way to retain.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a scroll view with paging control. It loads several pages according to an array, and each page has its table view.

```
   for(id name in categories) {

        NSLog(@"Loading Page.%i",i);
        NSLog(@"categories count:%i",[categories count]);

       TasksPageViewController *tasks = [[TasksPageViewController alloc] init] ;

       tasks = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TasksPageViewController"];

        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        tasks.view.frame = frame;

        [tasks populateWithData:(i-1) categoryName:name];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:tasks.view];

        i++;

    }
```

the .h file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainPageViewController.h"
#import "TasksPageViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

    // To be used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
    BOOL pageControlUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (IBAction)changePage;

@end
```

The UITableView though is returning

`*** -[TasksPageViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x68efac0`

(originally it was a `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`, but got this with NSZombiesEnabled)

I don't know how to proceed, I think I have to retain the `tasks` but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When adding the view of a view controller as a subview of a view you control, you need to retain the controller. keep it as a property with retain/strong, or an array of view controllers if there are many of them

in this case adding the view as a subview has retained it, so you still have a reference to the table view. but the view controller has been dealloc'd which is why the datasource (which is the view controller for UITableViewController) method is being sent to a deallocated instance

Also, why do you initialise the view controller, and then immediately instantiate it from the storyboard?

Comment: It was just a test, originally it was ` TasksPageViewController *tasks = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TasksPageViewController"];`

Comment: fair enough, i haven't really used storyboards so i was mainly just curious

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just created a mutable array and add every `tasks` into it.

Comment: I took some time to figure out how to instantiate a view without nibs, that's how. (I think haha, so I thought I could be wrong).

Comment: thanks. i never use xibs, so thats worth knowing for when i start using storyboards